# tufte-book not usable with lualatex if siunitx is loaded

Tags: fonts, luatex, tufte

The following MWE

```
\documentclass[nobib,nofonts]{tufte-book} % \documentclass{article} works
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\begin{document}
  Hello, World!
\end{document}
```

failes with

```
File: ot1pplx.fd 2004/09/06 font definitions for OT1/pplx.
)
luaotfload | resolve : sequence of 3 lookups yielded nothing appropriate.
! Font \OT1/pplx/m/n/10=pplr9t at 10pt not loadable: metric data not found or ba
d.
<to be read again> 
relax 
l.6 \begin{document}
                  
? 
! Emergency stop.
<to be read again> 
relax 
l.6 \begin{document}
                  
End of file on the terminal!
```

Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: works fine for me. Is your system up-to-date? Can you show the log-file?

Comment: works without error here as well